# Is a polynomial having $d+1$ coefficients related to how it uniquely satisfies $d+1$ points?

Tags: polynomials, coordinate-systems

A degree $d$ polynomial $p(x)=a_d x^d+a_{d-1} x^{d-1}+\cdots+a_1 x+a_0$ has $d+1$ coefficients. Is this fact related in any meaningful way to how a polynomial uniquely satisfies $d+1$ points with unique $x$-values? (unique in that it is the only polynomial of degree $d$ or less to satisfy these points).

Comment: This is a good question, I don't understand the close votes. A nice introduction to the concept of the dimension of a vector space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess "related in any meaningful way" can be interpreted too broadly, so the quetsion is not clear enough. Someone could give a perfect answer, that doesn't satisfy the reader because they find the explanation not meaningful or related enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every point it goes through gives you an equation of the $a_i$'s. After plugging in $d+1$ points, you get a system of $d+1$ equations with unknowns $a_0\dots a_d$, with a unique solution (if you haven't used the same x-value twice), meaning those points determine your polynomial function completely.

Comment: If you are going to write an answer, you do need to show that there is a **unique** solution $a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_d$, as you know that there are a system of $d+1$ equations in $d+1$ unknowns that have multiple solutions for $a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_d$ [or no solution].

Comment: In particular, you need to establish that plugging in $d+1$ points gives $d+1$ **linearly independent** equations!

Comment: If you use different x values, you will have an infinite amount of solutions, but they will give the same polynomial (it only differs on a multiple).

Comment: The fact that they are linearly independant follows from the determinant of the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)